# Gradle package resource distribution

Tags: java, gradle, jar, package

I am trying to find a way to package and distribute my frontend asset files so that they can be versioned and included as a dependency in other shared UI projects.

My goal is to have a gradle build that takes in a directory structure of source files (.js, .css, .jpg etc) and zips (or jars) them up in a distributable versioned package.

Is there a way I can use the java jar task to produce an archive in the build/libs folder that, when unjarred, matches a directory structure that I define?

Answer (score 1):

I think this works for my purposes. Never mind!

```
apply plugin: 'distribution'    

distributions {
    main {
        contents {
            into('js') {
                from { 'js' }
            }
            into ('img') {      
                from { 'img' }
            }
            into ('css') {
                from { 'css' }
            } 
        }
    }
}
```